# What alternative monetary unit can serve as the basis of a reserve currency while preventing a long term debt cycle?

Tags: government, currency, trade

The Bretton-Woods system established the rules for commercial and financial relations among the United States and its allies, and established the U.S. dollar as the world's reserve currency. The dollar was backed by gold, with the understanding that one could trade in their dollars for gold coins or  bars when necessary. However, the business of running a global empire is expensive. Numerous wars plagued the era due to the nation's rivalry with the Soviet Union and other communists states, such as Vietnam and Korea. In addition, there were numerous social programs at home that needed to be paid for that citizens expected their governments to fund, such as the Great Society and social security. All of these factors added to budget concerns, leading to the country running out of money. In response to this, President Nixon betrayed the trust between nations when he took the dollar off the gold standard, turning it into a completely fiat currency backed y nothing but faith that the U.S. could pay its bills on time. This allowed the U.S. to simply print more money when it needed to, or borrow it from other countries who wished to save in the American dollar. While this worked in the short term and allowed America to fund its priorities, it added to the deficit over time. This pushed the nation into a situation where it borrowed more than it produced, making it unable to ever pay back its debts.

This cycle of events have played out throughout history with all great empires, from the British to the Dutch, going back all the way to the Romans. A world power needs more money to fund its conquests, turns its currency into a fiat system, and eventually borrows too much money that it is unable to repay. This gradually leads to a collapse of the empire, as another rivals replaces it. In this world, I intend to prevent that sequence in building my world power. To do this, I need to create a stable currency that fulfills certain requirements:

1. The currency must be linked to something rare in nature.
2. That item must be considered a source of value to the world that can be traded in.
3. That item can be produced by a nation when absolutely necessary in order to keep the link to its currency, but not in large quantities all at once.

If I was building out an empire in a world from scratch, what could I link its currency to that would fulfill these parameters?

Comment: When you say "building an empire from scratch" do you want this currency to make sense from the start of the empire to the current day? So something like "computing power" is out.

Comment: Seems like the problem you are describing is "borrows too much", not anything inherent about a fiat or backed currency. Over-borrowing of backed currencies has happened many times, too.

Comment: "Hey random internet world-builders, what's a simple answer to this complex real-world problem which has bedeviled experts and is part of the tragedy of human existence?"

Comment: Nope, the Bretton-Woods system never allowed natural persons to *"trade in their dollars for gold coins or bars"*. One Troy ounce of fine gold was declared equivalent to 35 USD. Other central banks undertook to set fixed exchange rates of their national currencies to the US dollar and to exchange any amount of the local currency for US dollars at the agreed rate. No currency was exchangeable for gold as far as natural persons or commercial corporations were concerned. (And no, it doesn't work. Gold fulfills all the naive requirements, and yet this has not stopped economic collapses.)

Comment: I think the concept behind the question is fundamentally flawed.  Items 1 and 3 on your list will either be permanently incompatible, or will cause one to cancel out the other over time.  If a thing can be made, then making enough of it will eventually cause it to cease to be 'rare'.  This is exactly the problem with fiat currency.  The ability to create the item causes that item to *become* the fiat currency that you are trying to avoid.

Comment: @Harthag is right about 1 & 3 working against each other, you probably want something not easily producible yet difficult to destroy, how about tying your currency to the value of land somehow? simple price fixing of land values perhaps, you might have to exclude mineral rights from the price fixed sales as that can change intrinsic value of a bit of land considerably depending on what's under it, if the state owns enough land in lieu of gold reserves & fixes lease sale or land rents maybe, there's a bunch of other problems to consider of course but perhaps no more than with any other system.

Answer (score 2):

Lets go for a silly answer to a silly question. This technically meets the three criteria of the question.

#### Currency: High Explosives

> The currency must be linked to something rare in nature.

High explosives are rare in nature due to their instability.

> That item must be considered a source of value to the world that can be traded in.

Explosives have many uses.

- Mineral extraction.
- Military actions
- Construction
- Entertainment (Movies,)
- etc

> That item can be produced by a nation when absolutely necessary in order to keep the link to its currency, but not in large quantities all at once.

Explosives have been produced on mass by nations but producing it in really high volumes is.. risky. It is also to a degree self limiting a nation that tries to produce Mega tonnes of high explosives risk runaway inflation. This inflation will be made clear to everybody providing strong incentives to not allow this to happen.

Comment: Sounds like a variant on Larry Niven's tongue-in-cheek "The Roentgen Standard" https://larryniven.net/stories/roentgen.shtml